# How to write a function for randomize colors of an attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a grid of elements inside the body coded like this:

```
<ul>
<li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg" data-thumbnail-overlay-color="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
</ul>
```

My purpose is to randomize the `data-thumbnail-overlay-color=""` with a JavaScript function like this inside the body:

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

Since I'm not familiar with JavaScript, how should be written for the purpose?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @BenM Hi again Ben, I tried with this: `<script type="javascript">
var liIterator = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < liIterator.length; i++) {
    liIterator[i].setAttribute("data-thumbnail-overlay-color", '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
}
</script>` but I'm totally a disaster in JavaScript :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function get_random_color(){  
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); 
  var color = '#'; 
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) { 
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)]; 
    } 
  return color; 
  }

function GRC() {  
 var r = 'rgba('+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+','+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+', '+Math.floor(Math.random()*255)+', '+Math.random()+')'; 
  return r;
}


var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for(i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
    if(lis[i].hasAttribute('data-thumbnail-overlay-color')){
      var randomColor =  get_random_color()
      lis[i].setAttribute('data-thumbnail-overlay-color', randomColor);
      lis[i].setAttribute('style', 'color:'+randomColor);
      }
  }
```

```html
<ul>
<li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg" data-thumbnail-overlay-color="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg" data-thumbnail-overlay-color="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, I have many items inside my `<ul>` table so how could I use this solution for my purpose (I cannot change manually all `id`)

Comment: As @Carlos M. Meyer just noticed me, "for hexadecimal letters.length will be allways 16, don't need to recalculate in every loop.". I preferred to use `letters.length` because if you need only a range of colors, it won't break.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, set an id for the tag, generate an hex color code, and use the attr() function to set it:

```
<ul>
<li id="theTag_1" data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg" data-thumbnail-overlay-color="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
<li id="theTag_2" data-thumbnail-path="content/media/thumbnails/1.jpg" data-url="content/media/images/1.jpg" data-thumbnail-overlay-color="">
    <div>
        <p class="gallery1DecHeader">my second description</p>  
    </div>                                
</li>
... // more elements here with unique id each ("theTag_" + number)
</ul>

<script>
function setColorToID(id) {
    var hexNumbers = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); // convert to array
    var color = '#';
    for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++ ) {
       color += hexNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    $(id).attr("data-thumbnail-overlay-color" , color);
}

$('[id^="theTag_"]').each(function(){
        setColorToID(this.id);
    });
</script>
```

If you don't want to set and id for each, and this is the unique list in the page:

```
    <script>
    function setColorToID(id) {
        var hexNumbers = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); // convert to array
        var color = '#';
        for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++ ) {
           color += hexNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        $(id).attr("data-thumbnail-overlay-color" , color);
    }

$("li").each(function() {
            setColorToID(this);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have lot of elements inside the `<ul>` so I cannot use a unique id for the purpose.

Comment: you can get all with a similar id (commonId+ number), and use an foreach loop. One second, I'm editing to add that..

Comment: OK but also with this solution I must change all id's manually :(

Comment: How do you build this list? from a database? then you'll have and unique id for each element, use it, you don't need to use the numbers as I said. It will work with  id="theTag_whateverYouWantButNotDuplicated" , may be unordered numbers, letters or stings.

Comment: the list is built without using any id (as in my code above), and parse to a JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery you could do it like this:

You can simply work with the RGB attribute
with `Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 1);`
you can generate 3 different values from 0-250. 
remember: rgb works with `(0-250, 0-250, 0-250)`

Now you can simply take your object. And make it fancy
for this example ill randomize the background color since i don't know the attributes values on `data-thumbnail-overlay-color=""`

```
function randomColor(object){
   var red = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 1);;
   var green = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 1);
   var blue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 250) + 1);
   //
   $(object).css('background-color', 'rgb('+red+', '+green+', '+blue+')');
}
```